# Update web page whilst processing data

Tags: python, ajax, javascript-events, parallel-processing, pylons

Im not really sure what to search for on this subject.

I have a Pylons back end which loops over a list of email addresses in a database and then displays them on a web page. What I would like to do is have a loading section (as there are some other processes which take quite a while) to show which email address is currently being proccessed.

i.e
"currently processing: example@internet.com"
"currently processing: example2@internet.com"

Im open to using any technology available, although I suspect AJAX would be the answer. Im just a bit stumped for what to do, as if I return something to the front end web page, the process will end! There must be some sort of parallel processing, but I dont know how to go about it. So how can I show which email address is being processed on screen?

**Python**

```
emails = [a,b,c]
for x in emails:
   return x
```

**Javascript**

```
function displayProcess(email){
$('#emailDisplay').val(email)
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some sort of job queue for long-lasting tasks. [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) is quite popular in Python world. Jobs could report their status to some sort of quick and temporary data store, like [Redis](http://redis.io) and JavaScript could poll for those statuses using AJAX each, let's say, 5 seconds (I'm assuming it doesn't really matter if something has been processed 2 or 5 seconds ago).

**edit**

Just to clarify - in model I'm describing JavaScript doesn't call Redis directly. It uses some sort of service dumping needed data to JSON or XML.